# Calculate numbers like 2 + 3 + 1 in Ruby (from input)

Tags: ruby

Im trying to make a simple calculator in Ruby. Except this one should be able to calculate something like: 1 + 2 - 3, which doesn't seem to work so well. I think the syntax should be right (the part I'm having trouble with is Case).

Questions:

1. I launch the script as you normally would and enter the "1 + 1 + 1", and I get back "Invalid input". I don't understand why.
2. How could I improve the script. Is Case-statements the way to go? Or should I use if-statements instead?

```
def calculator
   puts "\tGreetings humanoid, im the Calculator."

   while true
      prompt = '>> '
      print prompt
      str = gets.chomp.split(" ")
      return if str[0] == 'q' 
      operand1 = str[0].to_i
      operand2 = str[2].to_i
      operand3 = str[4].to_i
      operator = str[1].to_sym
      operator2 = str[3].to_sym

      case 
      when operator == "+" && operator2 == "+"
         puts operand1 + operand2 + operand3
      when operator == "+" && operator2 == "-"
         puts operand1 + operand2 - operand3
      when operator == "-" && operator2 == "+"
         puts operand1 - operand2 + operand3 
      else
         puts "Invalid input"
      end
   end

end
if __FILE__ == $0
 calculator
end
puts "Okay :( , bye!"
```

Comment: Take a look at Dijkstra's Shunting Yard Algorithm. It'll make extending the input beyond three numbers and two operators trivial, and it's an interesting exercise to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You convert your operation signs to `Symbol`s and then compare them to `String`s:

```
#                 ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
operator = str[1].to_sym
#                ⇓⇓⇓
when operator == "+"
```

You should either leave them intact, or compare to symbols:

```
when operator == "+".to_sym
```

or, ever simplier:

```
when operator == :+
```